# Toggle class when anchor clicked for single div only

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jquery to toggle a class named "active" within my page to show my div.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <td>
    <nav id="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#">More <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                <div class="dropdownContain"><!-- active -->
                    <div class="triangle"></div>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Plan</li>
                        <li>Account Settings</li>
                        <li>Switch Account</li>
                        <li>Sign Out</li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>                                                            
             </li>
        </ul>
   </nav>
 </td>
```

And the toggle class jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".drop a").click(function(){
            $( "div.dropdownContain" ).toggleClass( "active" );
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The jQuery **does** work as expected, however say I have 2+ rows on my page, when I click any anchor on my page, it adds "active" to every single div named "dropdownContain" on my page.

How do I only add "active" to the corresponding div where the anchor was clicked? I could potentially have 100+ rows needing this code, therefore I can't have unique classes or id's for each element.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`next()`**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method like following.

```
$(".drop a").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div.dropdownContain").toggleClass( "active" );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! When I use this, the first row works as I originally intended, however the second row doesn't show or hide the div. Not to worry, I think this is an issue with using CSS id's more than once. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` to refer specifically to the link you're clicking on:

```
$(".drop a").click(function(){
    $(this).next("div.dropdownContain").toggleClass( "active" );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```js
$(".drop a").click(function() {
  $(this).next("div.dropdownContain").toggleClass("active");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">More <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

      <div class="dropdownContain">
        <!-- active -->
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <ul>
          <li>Plan</li>
          <li>Account Settings</li>
          <li>Switch Account</li>
          <li>Sign Out</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li class="drop">
      <a href="#">More <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

      <div class="dropdownContain">
        <!-- active -->
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <ul>
          <li>Plan</li>
          <li>Account Settings</li>
          <li>Switch Account</li>
          <li>Sign Out</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```